# Awesomium - Return object name

Tags: c#, javascript, wpf, awesomium

**Javascript / HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function configurator(clicked) 
{ 
       myGlobalObject.onLinkClicked(clicked.name);
} 
</script>

<a name="link1" href="#" onclick="configurator(this)">Link 1</a>
<a name="link2" href="#" onclick="configurator(this)">Link 2</a>
```

I'm using Awesomium's JSObject.bind method to invoke a Javascript method from C#. But I don't know how to return the link name (<a name='*return this to C#*'>) when the link clicked. Could someone help me?

**C#**

```
using (JSObject myGlobalObject = webControl1.CreateGlobalJavascriptObject("myGlobalObject"))
{
   myGlobalObject.Bind("onLinkClicked", true, (sen, eve) =>
   {
       //Don't know what code to write here....
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
clicked.getAttribute("name")
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a noob here. But, I get an error on the code (on clicked). Could you write the complete code please...